# Is riding shirtless safe?

Tags: safety, clothes, etiquette

During the summer, I like to go for rides on trails without a shirt. Is this safe?

Also, related: is it rude to other people on the trail not to wear a shirt?

Comment: Rude? In certain events it seems to be positively encouraged! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Naked_Bike_Ride

Comment: Try riding in a shirt with buttons, all of them undone. While a (cotton) T-shirt only gets wet with sweat, an unbuttoned shirt provides many benefits, such as sun protection, increased air flow, kickass style.

Comment: Having said that, during the hot summers I ride exclusively shirtless. Only places I have had problems with this are banks, large general stores and at work. And the realization about unbuttoned shirts came to me only last summer, while touring with panniers.

Comment: Cycling shirts are light enough to allow venting, and they generally have three pockets on the back.  If you go shirtless, how do you carry your stuff ?

Visibility is improved with a good colour of top, and down here in New Zealand you'd be sunburnt within a short time, in the height of summer.

Instead consider a close-fitting shirt made of coolmax.  Will have almost the same cooling effect of nothing, but will have solar protection, and increased visibilty if you choose white or grellow colours.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Safe is a relative term in this instance. A shirt might protect you in a fall, but only just. You'll know immediately whether a shirt can protect your skin from sticks, branches, and prickers dangling into the trail. If you were going fast enough flying insects may even make an impact, though I can't imagine it'd be terribly painful.

Shirts do offer some protection from two things: sunburns (and subsequent skin cancer) and bites from insects (potentially carrying disease.) For lightly complexioned people, skin cancer is a huge danger and can develop even without having been sunburned. Insect-borne diseases are also a big deal in most places. Having been treated for Lyme disease, I can attest to the importance of wearing insect repellent and, yes, shirts.

Additionally, that thin layer of material actually keeps you cooler by blocking the sun from reaching your skin - this is the same reason why desert dwelling peoples wear lightweight material all over their bodies. Having a shirt on also keeps you from sweating all over your bike and other gear.

In terms of etiquette: if you're out in the woods and there aren't many people around, go for it. If you're bumping elbows with people on a multi-use trail, maybe consider some modesty.

Comment: +1 for not getting sweat on your bike. Keep the bike safe.

Comment: I'd say you covered the issues.  The point about being cooler with a shirt on is important.  As for rudeness, it depends on your local norms for behavior (and, to an extent, your physique) -- on a sparsely traveled trail or on the open road I wouldn't find it offensive.  On a busy city park trail with kids and old folks and everyone in-between it's a bit more questionable.

Comment: Although a shirt won't stop gravel rash etc, it will help stop dirt entering wounds.

Answer (score 10):

**Safety**

- If you fall off, I can't see how a shirt would protect you. It might reduce grazes slightly, but it's negligible.
- A shirt may protect you from sunlight and risks of sunburn and skin cancer, although, unless it states UV protection, most shirts let some sunlight through.
- Depending on where/when you ride, you may be more at risk of insect bites or simply getting them stuck in your sweat - nice!

**Rudeness**

Bit of a personal opinion on whether it's rude. Personally I'm not bothered at all. I'm more offended by dry creaky chains. I *think* legally (in the UK, at least), it legal for anyone to show their bare chest in public, regardless of gender.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have little to no protection against scrapes on trees or bushes close to the trail. A shirt will give some protection from the sun, bugs/insects, and those who share the trail feel being shirtless is best saved for the beach or pool.

Answer (score 0):

A sleeveless cycling jersey offers no protection to the arms and might save a scratch or two in a light tumble.  It might save some gravel rash on the body.  It does offer protection against sunburn - but sunscreen the upper arms!

But for a shorter ride or say doing intervals on a warm day I find riding shirtless feels great so take the risk

Answer (score -1):

A typical shirt or bike jersey has no security benefits. Depending on the terrain some special protectors might make sense when thining about security. One might even argue that a shirt might reduce security as it might be caucght by a tree or something
Whether iit is "rude" depends on your local environment. In some areas it's absolutely accetable, in others not.

Answer (score -3):

Go shirtless!

If you've got a great body, then seeing you will give someone a boost!

If you've a terrible body, the seeing you will give someone a laugh!

So, it's a winner either way...

Comment: The question here is about safety - could you please [edit] your answer to address that point ?

Comment: @Criggie the question did also basically ask if riding shirtless violated social convention, to which Kev essentially answered that it doesn't matter. So ... in some sense, it is a plausible statement to make in response, although it doesn't actually answer that (subjective) question either.